# Keep an element by id in a html string using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html string that contains:

```
<div class="infodiv">
<p id="111"><span class="text">111</span></p>
<p id="222"><span class="text">222</span></p>
<p id="333"><span class="text">333</span></p>
</div>
```

I will put it on the infowindow content on Google Maps.

However, I want to remove some elements by id before showing on the infowindow.

For example: I want to keep only an element with id=111.

So, my html string will only show:

```
<div class="infodiv">
<p id="111"><span class="text">111</span></p>
</div>
```

Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: it's nearly impossible to achieve because we don't know that tomorrow which id you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to keep a single child of `.infodiv`, [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is a good choice.  Otherwise, take a look at the [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

Comment: Perfect. Just not is straight forward here.

Comment: _"I have a html string"_

Comment: The string can easily be rendered into DOM, filtered, and serialized to a string again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the `:not` css selector in jQuery after using `jQuery.parseHTML()`?

```js
$(".infodiv p:not(#111)").remove();
console.log($(".infodiv").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infodiv">
<p id="111"><span class="text">111</span><span></span></p>
<p id="222"><span class="text">222</span><span></span></p>
<p id="333"><span class="text">333</span><span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I have a html string"_ Where is HTML string converted to `DOM` element at Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$('.infodiv p:not(#111)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>An `id` of an HTML element cannot begin with digits [0-9]</strike>

[6 Basic HTML data types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

---

Substitute the first digit for a letter, for example `"a"` at `id` attribute at HTML.

To convert the HTML string to `DOM` elements you can set the HTML at `.innerHTML` of `<template>` element.

Create an array of last portion of `id`'s that should be removed from HTML string, iterate `.children` of parent element, call `.removeChild()` with `.querySelector()` and attribute ends with selector,  use `.replace()` to remove unnecessary newline characters from resulting HTML string.

```js
const html = `<div class="infodiv">
<p id="111"><span class="text">111</span></p>
<p id="222"><span class="text">222</span></p>
<p id="333"><span class="text">333</span></p>
</div>`;

const template = document.createElement("template");

template.innerHTML = html;

const p = template.content.children[0];

const not = ["222", "333"];

for (let id of not) {
  p.removeChild(p.querySelector(`[id="${id}"]`))
}

let parsedHTML = template.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, "");

console.log(parsedHTML);
```